# write a sql statement to update data for below query in sybase

Tags: sybase

we have table 1 :

### TABLE 1

```
(col1,col2) values(A,2)
(col1,col2) values(A,3)
(col1,col2) values(A,5)
(col1,col2) values(B,6)
(col1,col2) values(B,1)
(col1,col2) values(C,2)
```

now, we have table 2 :

### TABLE :2

```
(col1,col2) values(A,null)
(col1,col2) values(B,null)
(col1,col2) values(C,null)
```

write a query to update sum of indivisual of `col1`  from only 1 statement. Do not use a temp table .

### OUTPUT: table 2:

```
(col1,col2) values(A,9)
(col1,col2) values(B,7)
(col1,col2) values(C,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle variant (I hope that it is working on Sybase too):

```
create table TABLE1 (col1 varchar(1), col2 integer);

create table TABLE2 (col1 varchar(1), col2 integer);

insert into TABLE1 (col1,col2) values('A',2);

insert into TABLE1 (col1,col2) values('A',3);

insert into TABLE1 (col1,col2) values('A',5);

insert into TABLE1 (col1,col2) values('B',6);

insert into TABLE1 (col1,col2) values('B',1);

insert into TABLE1 (col1,col2) values('C',2);

insert into TABLE2 (col1,col2) values('A',null);

insert into TABLE2 (col1,col2) values('B',null);

insert into TABLE2 (col1,col2) values('C',null);

update TABLE2 t2 set COL2 = (select sum(t1.col2) from TABLE1 t1 where t1.col1 = t2.col1);

select * from TABLE2;
```

As can I remember, Sybase has own update syntax (can't check myself):

```
update TABLE2
set col2 = sum(t2.col1)
from TABLE1 t1, TABLE2 t2
where t1.col1 = t2.col2
```